# Logstash-7.1.1 is getting aborted in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to setup the Elasticsearch , Kibana and Logstash in the windows 2012R2.

Elasticsearch , Kibana working fine after the installation.

I am unable to start logstash, when I execute the command -( logstash.bat -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }" ) it gives the following error -

```
warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS= -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitia
tingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=
true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true -Djruby.jit.thresh
old=0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom ; pa
ss JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS
```

The logs folder did not create to chcek the logs.

Note: Logstash(7.1.1) is working fine in windows7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

JAVA_OPTS to -Xms512m -Xmx512m

in logstash7.1.1/config/jvm.options file

Answer (score 0):

Update the beginning of file bin\logstash.bat to set CLASSPATH & JAVA_OPTS as following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set params='%*'
set CLASSPATH=
set JAVA_OPTS=
```

Then Open PowerShell as admin and add JAVA_HOME env variable as following:

```
$env:JAVA_HOME ="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version"
```